# Which Automation tool we can use to automate secure application (in which we can't record video and screenshot?

Tags: automation, appium, android-uiautomator, appium-android

I want to automate one android native like Netflix app but i am not able to take screenshot / record video.
I tried with UIautomator/appium/katlon applications.
Can anyone suggest me another tools by which i can automate same native android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

You can only automate those apps that are signed with your company's/team provisioning profile from  their xcode build. The team will have to distribute this ipa/app file ready for your test (either the simulator version or for actual ios device - they are different build). Then once installed you will be asked to trust the app you installed.

Existing 3rd party apps are not possible as far as security is concerned.